# Deserialize Object with List using Gson

Tags: java, json, list, gson

I'm trying to deserialize a Json

```
{'empresa':{'areaAtuacao':{'areaAtuacao':'Primeiro','idAreaAtuacao':0},
'cnpjEmpresa':'561561','empresaAtivada':false,
'endereco':{'bairro':'Jardim Europa','cep':'85859318','cidade':'Foz do Iguaçu','complemento':'','estado':'PR','idEndereco':0,'logradouro':'Rua França','numero':'71'},
'idEmpresa':0,
'listaContato':[{'contato':'234234','idContato':0,'tipoContato':'Celular'},
    {'contato':'323423','idContato':0,'tipoContato':'Celular'},
    {'contato':'234234234','idContato':0,'tipoContato':'Celular'},
    {'contato':'324','idContato':0,'tipoContato':'Celular'},
    {'contato':'324','idContato':0,'tipoContato':'Celular'},
    {'contato':'3','idContato':0,'tipoContato':'Celular'},
    {'contato':'432','idContato':0,'tipoContato':'Celular'},
    {'contato':'432','idContato':0,'tipoContato':'Celular'},
    {'contato':'4','idContato':0,'tipoContato':'Celular'},
    {'contato':'23','idContato':0,'tipoContato':'Celular'},
    {'contato':'4234','idContato':0,'tipoContato':'Celular'},
    {'contato':'34','idContato':0,'tipoContato':'Celular'}],
'listaHorario':
    [{'diaSemana':{'diaSemana':'Segunda-Feira','idDiaSemana':0},'fimExpediente':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'fimIntervalo':{'year':2018      ,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'idHorarioEmpresa':0,'inicioExpediente':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'inicioIntervalo':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58}},
    {'diaSemana':{'diaSemana':'Terça-Feira','idDiaSemana':0},'fimExpediente':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'fimIntervalo':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'idHorarioEmpresa':0,'inicioExpediente':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'inicioIntervalo':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58}},
    {'diaSemana':{'diaSemana':'Quarta-Feira','idDiaSemana':0},'fimExpediente':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'fimIntervalo':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'idHorarioEmpresa':0,'inicioExpediente':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'inicioIntervalo':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58}},
    {'diaSemana':{'diaSemana':'Quinta-Feira','idDiaSemana':0},'fimExpediente':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'fimIntervalo':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'idHorarioEmpresa':0,'inicioExpediente':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'inicioIntervalo':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58}},
    {'diaSemana':{'diaSemana':'Sexta-Feira','idDiaSemana':0},'fimExpediente':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'fimIntervalo':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'idHorarioEmpresa':0,'inicioExpediente':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'inicioIntervalo':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58}},{'diaSemana':
    {'diaSemana':'Sábado','idDiaSemana':0},'fimExpediente':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'fimIntervalo':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'idHorarioEmpresa':0,'inicioExpediente':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'inicioIntervalo':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58}},
    {'diaSemana':{'diaSemana':'Domingo','idDiaSemana':0},'fimExpediente':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'fimIntervalo':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'idHorarioEmpresa':0,'inicioExpediente':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58},'inicioIntervalo':{'year':2018,'month':4,'dayOfMonth':15,'hourOfDay':20,'minute':16,'second':58}}],
'logoEmpresa':[-1,-40,-1,-32,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,-1,-31,33,65,69,120,105,102,0,0,73,73,42,0,8,0,0,0,9,0,15,1,2,0,18,0,0,0,-98,0,0,0,16,1,2,0,18,0,0,0,-80,0,0,0,18,1,4,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,26,1,5,0,1,0,0,0,122,0,0,0,27,1,5,0,1,0,0,0,-126,0,0,0,40,1,3,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,50,1,2,0,20,0,0,0,-118,0,0,0,19,2,3,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,105,-121,4,0,1,0,0,0,-62,0,0,0,36,1,0,0,72,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,72,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,50,48,49,56,58,48,53,58,49,53,32,50,48,58,49,54,58,49,57,0,69,109,117,108,97,116,111,114,45,71,111,108,100,102,105,115,104,0,69,109,117,108,97,116,111,114,45,71,111,108,100,102,105,115,104,0,7,0,0,-112,7,0,4,0,0,0,48,50,49,48,1,-111,7,0,4,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,10,-110,5,0,1,0,0,0,28,1,0,0,0,-96,7,0,4,0,0,0,48,49,48,48,1,-96,3,0,1,0,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,2,-96,4,0,1,0,0,0,-128,2,0,0,3,-96,4,0,1,0,0,0,-32,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,36,19,0,0,-24,3,0,0,2,0,1,2,4,0,1,0,0,0,66,1,0,0,2,2,4,0,1,0,0,0,-9,31,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-40,-1,-32,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,-1,-37,0,67,0,5,3,4,4,4,3,5,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,7,12,8,7,7,7,7,15,11,11,9,12,17,15,18,18,17,15,17,17,19,22,28,23,19,20,26,21,17,17,24,33,24,26,29,29,31,31,31,19,23,34,36,34,30,36,28,30,31,30,-1,-37,0,67,1,5,5,5,7,6,7,14,8,8,14,30,20,17,20],
'nomeFantasia':'jsdnjkfndkjn','publicoAlvo':'Unissex'},'encontrado':false,'idLogin':0,'senha':'B17EF6D19C7A5B1EE83B907C595526DCB1EB06DB8227D650D5DDA0A9F4CE8CD9','usuario':'51456'}
```

Using Gson's simple method

```
    Login dadosEmpresa = new Gson().fromJson(dados, Login.class);
```

However, when I analyze my object, Contact List and Company Schedule are empty.
[Object after deserialization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epKF0.png)

The classes used are as follows:

```
public class Login {

    private int idLogin;
    private String usuario;
    private String senha;
    private String loginGoogle;
    private Cliente cliente;
    private Empresa empresa;

    [...] Gets e Sets [..] }

       public class Empresa {

            private int idEmpresa;
            private String nomeFantasia;
            private String cnpjEmpresa;
            private String descricaoEmpresa;
            private byte[] logoEmpresa;
            private boolean empresaAtivada;
            private Calendar desativadaEm;
            private String genero;
            AreaAtuacao areaAtuacao = new  AreaAtuacao();
            Endereco endereco = new Endereco();
            List<HorarioEmpresa> horarioEmpresa = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Contato> contato = new ArrayList<>();
            List<ServicoPrestado> servicoPrestado = new ArrayList<>();

    [...] Gets e Sets [..] }

    public class Contato {

        private int idContato;
        private String contato;
        private String tipoContato;


    [...] Gets e Sets [..] }


    public class HorarioEmpresa {

        private int idHorarioEmpresa;
        private Calendar inicioExpediente;
        private Calendar inicioIntervalo;
        private Calendar fimIntervalo;
        private Calendar fimExpediente;
        private DiaSemana diaSemana;

    [...] Gets e Sets [..] }
```

I already used it

```
Type dados = new TypeToken<Login>() {}.getType();
```

But since I'm not working with a Login list, I did not get any differentiated effect from the first method.

Note: All other data that is not in the List is being set correctly.

Comment: English pls. Or ask the question on [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @PaulChu 
Sorry, I updated the question for English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice if you'd simply reduce the amount of code and the size of the JSON document you are going to deserialize.

Gson uses its `UnsafeAllocator` and `sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateInstance` under the hood (at least for my JVM instance) for classes that do not have default constructors.
This is required no *allocate* objects without their constructors being invoked, because Gson cannot construct inner classes properly: you're using *inner* classes that have an implicit compiler-generated constructor to reference its outer class *reference*.
For example, having the following classes

```java
class Login {

    Empresa empresa;

    class Empresa {

        List<Contato> contato = new ArrayList<>();

        class Contato {

            int idContato;
            String contato;
            String tipoContato;

        }

    }

}
```

invoking `Login.Empresa.class.getDeclaredConstructors()` will produce the only compiler-generated constructor: `q50361018.Login$Empresa(q50361018.Login)`.
I don't really remember, but initializers seem to be invoked right before constructor bodies (and probably are a part of constructor bodies).
This means that

```java
final UnsafeAllocator unsafeAllocator = UnsafeAllocator.create();
System.out.println(unsafeAllocator.newInstance(Login.Empresa.class).contato);
```

will return `contato` always set to `null` because no constructor was invoked and no field initializers are invoked.
However, the `contato` field *can* be set during deserialization.
At least if you fix its name to `listaContato` or annotate the field with `@SerializedName('listaContato')`.
So, the solution is just:

```java
class Login {

    Empresa empresa;

    class Empresa {

        // This is the solution 
        List<Contato> listaContato = new ArrayList<>();
        // Or the following
        // @SerializedName("listaContato")
        // List<Contato> contato = new ArrayList<>();
        // None of the solutions can fix the default empty array list though

        class Contato {

            int idContato;
            String contato;
            String tipoContato;

        }

    }

}
```

Or even better, avoid inner classes that serve data-transfer purposes (I personally avoid them at all costs if possible):

```java
class Login {

    Empresa empresa;

}


class Empresa {

    // This will always be an empty array list even if there is `listaContato` in the JSON document
    List<Contato> listaContato = new ArrayList<>();

}

class Contato {

    int idContato;
    String contato;
    String tipoContato;

}
```

All three classes above assume that they are package-level classes.

Demo:

```java
try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = Resources.getPackageResourceJsonReader(Q50361018.class, "whatever.json") ) {
    final Login login = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Login.class);
    login.empresa.listaContato
            .stream()
            .limit(2)
            .forEach(contato -> System.out.println(contato.idContato + " " + contato.contato + " " + contato.tipoContato));
}
```

Output:

```
0 234234 Celular
0 323423 Celular
0 234234234 Celular
```

Comment: Good afternoon, it worked perfectly for me your answer, I added the annotations `@SerializedName("ListaCotato") & @SerializedName ("listaHorario")`, since I had not noticed that the name of the Json variable was different from the class. Thank you